# Querying all tables to find tables that have a certain value in a specific column in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

For context, we have a variety of data sources being ingested into our Redshift instance. Our ingestion tool marks rows as deleted if they are deleted from the original source with a `marked_deleted` column.

Now this is where it gets kind of complicated, some of the sources we ingest data from already do this form of soft deletion and have their own `marked_deleted` or `deleted_at` columns. We're aware of these. But we'd like to find the tables that don't have soft deletes enabled on the data source. The tables that have their rows hard deleted.

**Does a query exist that can query all tables on a Redshift instance to find out where `marked_deleted = true` and return a list of those table names?** We have 250+ tables already and that number is set to grow fast, so ideally we would like a query we can periodically run to update the list of tables we need to be aware of that contain hard deletes.

I have no idea where to even begin with a query like this, so any information is helpful!